# How to create csv file using spring Rest WebServices?

Tags: spring, jackson

I want to produce csv file for the given pojo class by using spring restful webservice api. How do I do that ?

Comment: Write a program for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
package net.codejava.spring.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.codejava.spring.model.Book;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.supercsv.io.CsvBeanWriter;
import org.supercsv.io.ICsvBeanWriter;
import org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference;

/**
 * This Spring controller class implements a CSV file download functionality.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
@Controller
public class CSVFileDownloadController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV")
    public void downloadCSV(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String csvFileName = "books.csv";

        response.setContentType("text/csv");

        // creates mock data
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
                csvFileName);
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        Book book1 = new Book("Effective Java", "Java Best Practices",
                "Joshua Bloch", "Addision-Wesley", "0321356683", "05/08/2008",
                38);

        Book book2 = new Book("Head First Java", "Java for Beginners",
                "Kathy Sierra & Bert Bates", "O'Reilly Media", "0321356683",
                "02/09/2005", 30);

        Book book3 = new Book("Thinking in Java", "Java Core In-depth",
                "Bruce Eckel", "Prentice Hall", "0131872486", "02/26/2006", 45);

        Book book4 = new Book("Java Generics and Collections",
                "Comprehensive guide to generics and collections",
                "Naftalin & Philip Wadler", "O'Reilly Media", "0596527756",
                "10/24/2006", 27);

        List<Book> listBooks = Arrays.asList(book1, book2, book3, book4);

        // uses the Super CSV API to generate CSV data from the model data
        ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(response.getWriter(),
                CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

        String[] header = { "Title", "Description", "Author", "Publisher",
                "isbn", "PublishedDate", "Price" };

        csvWriter.writeHeader(header);

        for (Book aBook : listBooks) {
            csvWriter.write(aBook, header);
        }

        csvWriter.close();
    }
}
```

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-csv-file-download-example